# Creating a matching game in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a class for a matching game in a 5x5 grid. The user will pick the ranges, based on row and column number. I've spent the last couple hours trying to figure out how to set this up, and I'm thinking it should either be a set or a list of tuples with the x,y coordinates. I can get the list of coordinates generated in a set, by doing:

```
board = set((x,y)
        for x in range(5)
        for y in range(5))
```

I can't figure out how to actually turn this into a workable board though. I am trying to create a "real board" with the matched values, and a "show" board that just has X's until the user gets the match, and then the real values will be shown on their board.

So ideally, there should be one board that looks like

```
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
```

and another with random pairs:

```
A M F H I
C D B J E
G I F A C
D J G H L
K E L B M
```

Comment: Maybe you should try a 4x5 board, or a 5x6 board? Because a 5x5 board has an odd number of locations, which is kind of hard to fill with _matching pairs_.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a better way to represent the board is to use a dictionary:

```
board = {}
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(5):
        board[x, y] = 'X'
```

You can update a character by doing: `board[3, 4] = 'D'`.

You can even specify the board using a [dictionary comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
board = {(x, y): 'X' for x in range(5) for y in range(5)}
```

Comment: This seems a little simpler than the list solution. As far as updating the characters goes, I know I need to generate a second table with the random values, its part of my guidelines, as well as the user inputing the cordinates on the grid to reveal the element. Would I just do the same as you've done above, but add a while loop to randomly add variables up to 2 times? And even after this is figured out, how can I make the grids corrospond to the cordinates?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a list of lists:

```
board = []

def initializeBoard(board):
    for i in range(5):
        board.append([])
    for l in board:
        for i in range(5):
            l.append('X')

def printBoard(board):
    for l in board:
        for e in l:
            print e,
        print 


initializeBoard(board)
board[0][1] = 'A' # To access an element        
printBoard(board)

>>> 
X A X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
X X X X X
```